# Vbscript - Reusing LDAP object?

Tags: vba, vbscript, ldap

I was using ADSI Scriptomatic and I've noticed that these examples require a username `strName`, but I want to do a whole batch of operations to both pull data from AD and put data back as well. I was just wondering what happens to the objRootDSE object when I've pulled or put data in it?

```
Public Sub createADCommand(Optional strContainer As String)
    Set objRootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://rootDSE")
    If strContainer = "" Then
        Set objItem = GetObject("LDAP://" & _
        objRootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext"))
    Else
        Set objItem = GetObject("LDAP://cn=" & strName & "," & strContainer & "," & _
        objRootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext"))
    End If
End Sub
```

The reason I'm asking is because I want to reuse this object if it's memory intensive in some way. I want the code to be as efficient as possible. But I'm not sure if LDAP is a heavy protocol or not? I know the "L" is for "Lightweight" :p But I see no point in closing an object if I'm just gonna reopen it again.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, LDAP isn't relevant. Instead, your variable "objItem" is storing whatever it collects (in this case, data from LDAP). And you don't have to worry about putting it back, unless you want to change, remove, or add the LDAP data.